# Greatest possible perimeter

Tags: geometry

What is the greatest possible perimeter of a right-angled triangle with integer side lengths if one of the sides has length 12 cm?
Explain the procedure

(Answer=84 cm)

Comment: If we as a guess take the triad (12,13,5) of perimeter 30 we scale to multiply by 12/5 or, 12/5* 30 = 72.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously 12 must be the base for maximum perimeter

By Pythagoras theorem

$144 = a^2-c^2$

So $144= (a-c)(a+c) $

For maximum perimeter we need $a+c$ maximum. $a+c =144$ dosent give integer solutions for a and c. The next largest choice on factoring $144$ is $72$ This gives integer solutions. Hence perimeter is $84$

Note: Here $a$ is the hypotenuese and $c $ is the other base.

Answer (score 2):

You have to think of the Pythagorean Theorem.

Let $a,b$ be the legs of the triangle and $c$ be the hypoteneuse.  Then, of course:

$a^2=c^2-b^2=(c+b)(c-b)$

Here, you have $a=12$ so $a^2=144$.  So the whole numbers $b$ and $c$ must be selected so that their sum times their difference equals $144$.

For any two whole numbers the sum and difference are both even or both odd.  To make the product $144$ you have to make the sum and difference both even, so you choose a pair of even numbers with that product.  Let's try $18$ and $8$.  The larger of these two factors is $c+b=18$ and the smaller one is $c-b=8$.  Then $c$ is the average of these two numbers, thus $c=13$, and that leaves $b=5$.  Note that even though the sum and difference must be even each individual side can be odd (if so, both are odd).

For the triangle above, then, the perimeter is $a+b+c=12+5+13=30$, which is not the maximum.  That's because I deliberately made a poor choice of factors for $144$.  Your job is to find a pair of even factors of $144$ so that the larger one, being the sum of the other two sides, is *as big as you can get it*.  Then you get the maximum perimeter you want.

Comment: Please explain to me what was wrong.  I cannot figure out myself why I was downvoted.

Comment: I find your answer is better than the other with an upvote.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN: Your answer is good, dear friend, but good is not optimal. (neither Oscar Lanzi's answer!)

Comment: @Piquito will keep that in mind